# Remove List Item Before Create New using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have not much experience in javascript. I have one function in javascript is like below

```
function createDownloadLink(blob) {
    
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    //name of .wav file to use during upload and download (without extendion)
    var filename = new Date().toISOString();

    //add controls to the <audio> element
    au.controls = true;
    au.src = url;

    //save to disk link

    //add the new audio element to li
    li.appendChild(au);

    
    //upload link
    var upload = document.createElement('a');
    upload.classList.add('mybutton');
    upload.href="#";
    upload.innerHTML = "Upload";
    upload.addEventListener("click", function(event){
          var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.onload=function(e) {
              if(this.readyState === 4) {
                  console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText);
              }
          };
          var fd=new FormData();
          fd.append("audio_data",blob, filename);
          xhr.open("POST","upload.php",true);
          xhr.send(fd);
    })
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode (" "))//add a space in between
    li.appendChild(upload)//add the upload link to li

    //add the li element to the ol
    recordingsList.appendChild(li);
}
```

Its create recording list on press Stop Button. Instead I want discard if there old list and show only last one. Means I do not need multiple list, Instead I want only single one.
Current list looking like below image.
[image]

Let me know if anyone here can help me for achieve my goal.
Thanks!

Comment: try to remove child before appendChild: recordingsList.removeChild(li);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the old ones before you add the new one.

```
// Clear all previous recordings and add the new one
recordingsList.innerHTML = '';
recordingsList.appendChild(li);
```